# VB6 Search Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm running a program that validates the input of the text field via Access database. Here's a sample code:

```
Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus()
If TextBox <> "" Then
    With recordset
        .Index = "PrimaryKey"
        .Seek "=", TextBox
        If .NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "Record does not exist!", vbExclamation, Me.Caption
            TextBox = ""
            TextBox.SetFocus
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

I always get the error that the "PrimaryKey" is not an index. I need help.

Almost forgot. Here's the code when the form loads:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
CenterForm
Me.Top = 0
Set database = OpenDatabase("p:\location\file.mdb")
Set recordset = database.OpenRecordset("table")
End Sub
```

Comment: Find does not need an index.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the database you have to define the field PrimaryKey as an Index.

Please see Microsoft's documentation here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-remove-a-primary-key-07b4a84b-0063-4d56-8b00-65f2975e4379

As for the seek/index checking... try this:

Try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus()
If TextBox <> "" Then
  If NOT recordset.Supports(adIndex) THEN MSGBOX("AdIndex not supported")
IF NOT recordset.Supports(adSeek) Then MSGBOX("adSeek not supported")

    With recordset
        .Index = "PrimaryKey"
        .Seek "=", TextBox
        If .NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "Record does not exist!", vbExclamation, Me.Caption
            TextBox = ""
            TextBox.SetFocus
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

this will tell you whether seek or index is not allowed using the provider you have. Switching the OLE provider may be your answer.

Comment: can the seek method be done without the index? if so, how?

Comment: I havent used Access or VB6 in so long... but it depends on the provider you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> can the seek method be done without the index? if so, how?

No, seek needs the index. But you can iterate through all records; depending on the number of records this may be a serious performance issue.